# jquery show and trigger element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a notification system for my website, but am having problem for some unknown reason. I have a link when a user clicks it, it fire off a JavaScript function, then checks if a `div` is hidden, if it is hidden, it show it and load a PHP script within that `div`.

I probably overlooked something

my JavaScript code:

```
// show notifications
$(".noti_bubble").click(function () {
    // check the visibility of the element
    if($(".show-note").is(":hidden")) {
        $(".show-note").show();
        alert('noti_bubble has been perform');
        $(".show-note").load("scripts/notifications.php");
    }else{
        $(".show-note").hide();

    }

});
```

my html code:

```
<div style="width:900px; margin:0 auto;">
<div style="width:250px; float:right;">

<div class="dhtmlgoodies_contentBox" id="box1">
<div class="dhtmlgoodies_content" id="subBox1">
<!-- slide down content goes here -->
<div id="notiHeading" class="notiHeadingContent">
<strong>Notifications</strong>
</div>

<div class="notif_barline"></div>

<div id="notifyContent">

<div class="show-note"></div>

</div>

</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

the `.show-note` has a css of `display:none;` as well.

the clickable link:

```
<a href="#" id="dhtmlgoodies_control"  onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:slidedown_showHide('box1');" class="noti_bubble">(0)</a>
```

Comment: So, what is the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: it doesn't load $(".show-note").load("scripts/notifications.php");, the alert show up though.

Comment: for one thing you don't need the `javascript:` tag in your onmousedown. and two `hidden` and `display:none` are not the same thing so make sure that your context is right. `none` removes the element from the dom. hidden leaves the element in the dom but just makes it invisible.

Comment: @Raphael: What does your console tell you about the AJAX request to `scripts/notifications.php`? Does it show an error? Do you get the expected result?

Comment: NITPICK: store `$(".show-note")` into a variable and reference that variable in the code. Every time it is called, you are making the browser look up the element in the DOM.

Comment: I think you have to return false in the $(".noti_bubble").click function, you can also remove onclick="return false" from the <a>-tag

Comment: @Colin, the console doesn't show any error message, and I don't  got any result.

Comment: @ryan: display:none does not remove the element from the dom, but the browser stops reserving space for it.

Comment: @Raphael: Check the "Network" area of your console for the specific information regarding the AJAX request.

Comment: @Colin: The "Network" shows that it's requesting the php script and displays the right information in the preview tab. but it doesn't display it in the div for some reason.

Comment: If you are going to store $('.show-note') in a variable, make it a local of the event handler, then you dont have a ugly global and the lookup time isnt that problematic, so var div = $('.show-note'); in the event handler and then if (div.is(':hidden')) etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the [complete callback to `.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$(".show-note").load("scripts/notifications.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
    alert(status);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but how would i append it to a div on page?

Comment: So, what does it alert? Does the page still not load into the div?

Comment: So what has changed? The callback won't affect the behavior - it was just a debugging statement to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/9M396/

html

```
<div style="width:500px; margin:0 auto;">
    <div style="width:250px; float:right;">    
        <div class="dhtmlgoodies_contentBox" id="box1">
            <div class="dhtmlgoodies_content" id="subBox1">
            <!-- slide down content goes here -->
                <div id="notiHeading" class="notiHeadingContent">
                    <strong>Notifications</strong>
                </div>

                <div class="notif_barline"></div>

                <div id="notifyContent">                
                    <div class="show-note"></div>                
                </div>            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <a href="#" id="dhtmlgoodies_control" onmousedown="javascript:slidedown_showHide('box1');" class="noti_bubble">(0)</a>
```

js:

```
// show notifications
$(".noti_bubble").click(function () {
    var div = $(".show-note");

    if(div.is(":hidden")) {
        div.show();
        div.load("/echo/json/?json={}");
    }else{
        div.hide();
    }

    return false;
});
```

css:

```
div
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.show-note
{
    min-height: 100px;
    display:none;
}
```